# JSF 1.2 t:dataTable how to call javascript function with parameters

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-1.2

Hello I would like to ask how could I call javascript function on element click and pass some parameters to that function? I am using JSF 1.2

```
<t:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{rowData.data}" var="row">
    <h:commandLink onclick="alertMe(?, ?)">
        <h:outputText value="#{row[1]}"/>   
    </h:commandLink>
</t:dataTable>


function alertMe(x, y) {
    alert(x);
    alert(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to call it like this

```
<h:commandLink onclick="alertMe('#{row[1]}', '#{row[2]}')">
       <h:outputText value="My Text"/>
</h:commandLink>
```